# Image recognition sample size, Is larger sample size necessary for objects that are exactly equivalent pictures?

Tags: machine-learning

I currently have a list of every letter, capital letter in the alphabet. The font is constant, i.e. my inputs will always be the same font.

Given that the font is constant, do I really need multiple letters or can I train a program using 1 letter each? If I need multiple images for each letter, can I just run the same image through the machine learning algorithm and pretend it's a second image? (note that since the fonts are the same, a second image would be exactly the same).

It's a lot of work to 'print screen' then capture the specific letter one at a time, so I'm basically wondering if I can just copy and paste all the images 50 times to make my 52 sample size turn into 2600 sample size.

I'm using scikit-learn on python and will be testing various supervised learning algos to recognize the letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) not only has to distinguish between different letters, but also contend with issues like small rotations, translations or deformations.

A useful neural net (a common model for OCR) will need to be trained against labeled data that includes these transforms.  You could perhaps get away with starting with one image per letter, and programmatically rotating and translating it in increments to produce many labeled training examples.

For that matter, for the "original" examples surely you can render individual letters with your desired font and save them to a file, rather than using literal screen capture.

Comment: I don't get why I need to deal with rotations, other transforms, etc because there won't be those deformations since the input is always the same font and size. Regarding not using literal screen capture, the letters are provided to me as a screenshot so I don't have a choice there. So the question remains...can I use just 52 of the same examples multiplied say 50 times each?

Comment: It depends on your application.  The classic/original OCR app is recognizing hand-written US mailing ZIP codes. There, the envelope might not be under the camera exactly straight (rotation), might be off to one side (translation) or the writing might be sloppy (other deformations.)  If this sounds like you, then you'll need training examples of these.  If it does not, then perhaps you don't.